# Remove discontinuous time points in longitudinal data

Tags: r, data.table, panel-data, longitudinal

I have a firm-year longitudinal data but the year is not continuous for some firms, for example

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(firm_id=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)),year=c(1990,1991,1999,2000,2001,1995,1997,2008,2009,2010))
```

For each firm, I want to keep observations in the most recent continuous years and remove other observations. For example, Firm 1 has five-year observations in (1990, 1991, 1999, 2000, 2001) and I want to keep (1999, 2000, 2001)

[image: data.table(firm_id=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3)),year=c(1999,2000,2001,2008,2009,2010))]

I can think of some awkward approaches to solve this issue but I am wondering if there is an easy way to solve it.

Enlighted by the comments, I am also wondering if there is any way to keep the longest continuous vector block of years. For example,

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(firm_id=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)),year=c(1990,1991,1992,2000,2001,1995,1997,2008,2009,2010))
```

The result would be

[image]

Comment: What would happen 1) if you have data for 1990, 1991, 1992, 2000, 2001. Do you still keep 2000 and 2001? 2) if you have data as 1990, 1991, 1993, 1994, 1995, 2000. Which values do you keep?

Comment: Great question. 1) I was thinking to keep either the longest continuous block of the year vector or the most recent continuous block. 2) In this situation, it seems keeping any year is meaningless but I would rather keep  
the data in 2000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(data.table)
DT2 <- setorder(dt, firm_id, year)[
 ,d := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(year) > 1)), by = .(firm_id) ][
 ,n := .N, by = .(firm_id, d) ]

DT2
#     firm_id  year     d     n
#       <num> <num> <int> <int>
#  1:       1  1990     1     3
#  2:       1  1991     1     3
#  3:       1  1992     1     3
#  4:       1  2000     2     2
#  5:       1  2001     2     2
#  6:       2  1995     1     1
#  7:       2  1997     2     1
#  8:       2  2008     3     3
#  9:       2  2009     3     3
# 10:       2  2010     3     3
```

From here, if you want runs of 3 consecutive years or more, then

```r
DT2[ (n > 2), ]
```

If you want the longest run for each `firm_id`, then

```r
DT2[, .SD[n == max(n),], by = .(firm_id) ]
```